# Not able to create event for room resource calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have set up a google service account with Domain-wide delegation permissions. I am using Google Calendar APIs to manage the calendar events. Here is the sample code snippet:

```
InputStream inputstream = null;
    try {
        inputstream = new ByteArrayInputStream(this.key);
        Credential cred = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
            .setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory())
            .setServiceAccountId(cs.getGoogleServiceAccountId())
            .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR))
            .setServiceAccountUser("c_188d28jockafkhljibdpn05gio6iq@resource.calendar.google.com")
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(SecurityUtils.loadPrivateKeyFromKeyStore(SecurityUtils.getPkcs12KeyStore(), 
                                                                                    inputstream,"notasecret",
                                                                                    "privatekey", "notasecret"))
            .build();
        calendar = new Calendar.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), cred).setApplicationName("applicationName").build();
        
        Event e = new Event().setSummary("Test");
        e.setDescription("Test");
        e.setStart(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(new DateTime(new Date().getTime())));
        e.setStart(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(new DateTime(DateUtils.addHours(new Date(), 1).getTime())));
        Event insert = calendar.events().insert("c_188d28jockafkhljibdpn05gio6iq@resource.calendar.google.com", e).setSendNotifications(true).execute();
        logger.info("event created = {}", JsonUtil.getJSONString(insert));
    }
    finally {
        if(inputstream != null) {
            inputstream.close();
        }
    }
```

It gives the following exception when I try to create an event in the room resource calendar:

```
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Invalid email or User ID"
}
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:326)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:346)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:397)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:494)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:880)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:541)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:474)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:591)
```

It works fine when I try to create an event in any active user's calendar by replacing the resource email id with a particular user's email. What could be the issue?

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.  [example]

Comment: You mentioned you're using a service account to create the events, does the service account impersonate a user? Is the resource outside the domain? Is the resource shared with the user? Can you confirm if the resource is not occupied? Have you tried another resource? And one last thing, if you're impersonating, try creating the event with that user in the Google Calendar interface and see if you still get an error.